# Pass data from function to another inside the same class

Tags: ruby

I have the following class:

```
class Foo
  def [](*files)
  end

  def read(file)
  end
end
```

And I want to call the function read like this:

```
bar = Foo.new
bar['todo.txt'].read
```

Is there a way to make this syntax possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to chain those methods, I believe you will have to return `self` from `[]`.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :files
  def [](*files)
    @files = files
    self
  end

  def read
    p @files
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use instance variable to share context among instance methods.

```
class Foo
  def [](*files)
    @files = files
    self
  end
  def read(file = nil)
    if file
      File.read(file)
    else
      @files.map{|file| File.read(file)}.join
    end
  end
end
```